# Rsync stopped syncing files

Tags: rsync

I recently moved to a new server and my rsync script that ran perfect for months stopped working.  I'm at a loss for why.  I have a 'dev' server and production server.  When I run the following command I want the files on the dev server to get pushed to production.

```
rsync -avzP --exclude '.ssh' /var/www/ www-data@$HOST:/var/www
```

When I run the bash script (just the line above with host declared) it outputs as follows

```
www-data@dev:~/core$ ./publish.sh
sending incremental file list
rsync: [generator] failed to set times on "/var/www/.": Operation not permitted (1)
./
template/base/head.php
          7,811 100%    6.78MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=35/5346)

sent 123,884 bytes  received 756 bytes  83,093.33 bytes/sec
total size is 203,327,243  speedup is 1,631.32
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
```

when I run it again it acts like it synced

```
www-data@dev:~/core$ ./publish.sh
sending incremental file list
rsync: [generator] failed to set times on "/var/www/.": Operation not permitted (1)
./

sent 123,081 bytes  received 659 bytes  82,493.33 bytes/sec
total size is 203,327,235  speedup is 1,643.18
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
```

These files are both on webserver and need to be user/group www-data.  However I can't make /var/www folder owned by www-data...so that is why I am getting the error.  The /var/www is owned by root:root.  Not sure if that has something to do with this but I don't know a way around it.  This problem is very easy to reproduce.  An example is /var/www/template/base/head.php.  Below shows permissions on all files. md5 has is different between files.  Times + timezones are exactly the same between servers.  Thanks for any ideas. I have none.

Local Machine

```
www-data@dev:~/template/base$ ls -l
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 14  2022 block
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 29  2020 component
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1363 Dec  7  2020 favicon.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  299 Nov 18  2021 foot_js.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1174 May 14  2022 foot.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 25  2020 frame
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  716 May 16  2022 head_css.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 7803 Oct 10 14:47 head.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  670 Dec  7  2020 setting.php
www-data@dev:~/template/base$
```

Remote Machine

```
root@xxxx:/var# ls -l
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Oct  3 00:00 backups
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Aug 20 19:59 cache
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root  4096 Aug 28 15:17 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff 4096 Jul 14 16:00 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Aug 20 19:54 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Oct  8 00:00 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail  4096 Aug 20 19:54 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 20 19:54 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4 Aug 20 19:54 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 20 19:54 spool
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root  4096 Oct 10 14:39 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Sep  9 12:38 www
root@xxxx:/var#
```

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 14  2022 block
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 29  2020 component
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1363 Dec  7  2020 favicon.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  299 Nov 18  2021 foot_js.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1174 May 14  2022 foot.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 25  2020 frame
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  716 May 16  2022 head_css.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 7803 Oct  6 06:50 head.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  670 Dec  7  2020 setting.php
root@xxxx:/var/www/template/base#
```

Comment: `The /var/www is owned by root:root. Not sure if that has something to do with this` this is most likely the problem. What keeps you from changing it?

Comment: Please provide `ls -ld /var/www /var/www/template /var/www/template/base /var/www/template/base/head.php` in your question. I wonder if you may have omitted to give `www-data` any permissions to write to the intermediate directories. It certainly can't write to `/var/www` itself, which means it can't write or update any files in that root